# bootstrap btn-group radio buttons not working on live server

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-button

I am using bootstrap btn-group class for radio buttons.They are not working on live server.My site is under development example.com  .Although they work on a separate html page.

```
  <div class="row">
<section class="col-lg-2 col-xs-3">
<label>Gender:</label></section>
<section class="col-lg-4 col-xs-8">
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

  <label class="btn btn-primary control-label input-group">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="option2" autocomplete="off" value="male">Male
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary ">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="option3" autocomplete="off" value="female" checked> Female
  </label>
</div>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: No specific problems relative to my try on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/312zpxtL/). Any console errors ?

Comment: @Zeratops actually its already working on a plain html on local machine but on my website its not working.And no console errors

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn > input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <div class="row">
<section class="col-lg-2 col-xs-3">
<label>Gender:</label></section>
<section class="col-lg-4 col-xs-8">
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

  <label class="btn btn-primary control-label input-group">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="option2" autocomplete="off" value="male">Male
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary ">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="option3" autocomplete="off" value="female" checked> Female
  </label>
</div>
</section>
</div>
```

Add

```
.btn > input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
```

in your css

Comment: did you import bootstrap.min.js file and before that import jquery file too

Comment: actually its already working on a plain html on local machine but on my website its not working

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.gender').on('click', function() {
      $('.checked').removeClass('checked');
      $(this).addClass('checked');
    });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.checked {
  background-color: #286090;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <section class="col-lg-2 col-xs-3">
    <label>Gender:</label>
  </section>
  <section class="col-lg-4 col-xs-8">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

      <label class="btn btn-primary control-label input-group gender">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="option2" autocomplete="off" value="male">Male
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary gender">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="option3" autocomplete="off" value="female" checked> Female
      </label>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```